# Change button color with click in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, button

I am trying to change the button color on my form in VB.net to red upon click.  I have used the code below but I keep getting errors.

```
Button1.BackColor = Color.Gold
```

This gets me two errors.  The first is " 'BackColor' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' " and the second error is " 'Gold' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Media.Color' "  Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: From the namespaces used is clearly WPF

Comment: I know, I was trying to lead him/her to the right tags/title

Comment: I've never heard of `System.Windows.Controls`... Is this specific for WPF or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Button1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gold
```

Comment: Does that make it an answer?

Comment: Yes it does.  Works like charm.  Sorry for the delay but I was out sick the past few days